# Cas particulier de position de l'adjectif : « jeune x » vs « x jeune »

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, société

Il existe une différence entre « un jeune homme » et « un  homme jeune »; il ne semble pas y avoir de différence entre  « une jeune femme » et « une  femme jeune »; est-ce vraiment le cas? Quelqu'un aurait-il une explication plausible?

On trouve ceci dans le TLFi,

> « En partic. [Jeune antéposé forme avec un certain nombre de subst. des loc. subst. désignant une pers. à un moment de sa vie] Jeune femme*, fille*, garçon*, homme*, personne*; jeunes gens*.
>   [Jeune postposé qualifie les subst. entrant dans les loc. supra] C'est encore un homme jeune, mais ce n'est plus un jeune homme »,

mais il semble que ce ne soit vraiment caractéristique que de « homme », « fille » et « gens ».

Par exemple, un jeune homme est un garçon qui vient de sortir de l'adolescence et un homme jeune est un homme qui peut avoir atteint sa pleine maturité; il semble que cela ne soit pas vrai pour le mot femme; ma raison pour suspecter cela est qu'il est fréquent d'entendre les gens utiliser le terme « jeune homme » pour interpeller des personnes qui correspondent à ce terme et que jamais le terme « jeune femme » ne sera entendu; il manque apparemment quelque chose.

Comment: On dira merci à Sarah pour : https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00651838/document

Comment: @aCOSwt Cet article est à ne pas négliger dans l'enveloppe du sujet, mais il doit être suivi par une étude des cas particulier; il y a plus sur « jeune » dans le TLFi que dans cet article.

Comment: je n'ai pas de source, mais il me semble que l'on parle de jeune homme/jeune fille/jeunes gens dans le sens "pas encore tout à fait adulte", mais que dans les autres cas cela fait référence à l'âge. Peut-être parce que femme est souvent associé à "épouse" (mari et femme), donc déjà "adulte".

Comment: @ radouxju Selon vous, la correspondance entre « jeune homme » et  « jeune femme » serait imparfaite parce que le mot « femme » serait stigmatisé en raison de sa signification en tant que « épouse ». Cela me semble une fine remarque; il est dommage que ce soit si difficile à vérifier.

Comment: Habitude familliale, régionale ou carrément nationale je n'en sais rien, mais chez moi (En belgique Wallone) dans certains cas, "jeune homme" et "jeune fille" décrivent aussi des personnes célibataires, souvent d'un certain âge d'ailleurs. Il n'est pas rare d'entendre parler de "vieux jeune homme" ou de "vieille jeune fille"...

Answer (score 2):

On entend parfois « jeune femme » par exemple dans des expressions comme « cette jeune femme là-bas », « jeune femme » ayant alors le même sens que « jeune homme », mais « jeune homme » peut aussi être l'équivalent de  « mademoiselle », par exemple quand on s'adresse à la personne en question (serveur/euse, élève etc). « jeune femme » est moins utilisé que « jeune homme » simplement parce que ce dernier à deux sens au lieu d'un.

Comment: Il faudrait préciser pourquoi deux sens rendent l'utilisation moins importante; cela vous semble simple  mais ce n'est pas clair ; quels sont ces deux sens?

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il y a une différence :

- Un **jeune homme**, ce peut être soit un adolescent (pas encore un homme jeune donc), soi un jeune adulte (un homme jeune).
- Une **jeune femme**, ce ne peut être qu'une jeune adulte (une femme jeune) car une adolescente, c'est une **jeune fille** jusqu'à plus ou moins sa majorité.

  À l'opposé, **jeune garçon** ne s'emploie plus beaucoup après l'entrée dans l'enseignement secondaire.

Answer (score 0):

En réunissant les contributions de radouxju (commentaires) et Jean-Abdel (réponse) on peut spéculer plus sérieusement sur la validité de certaines hypothèses.

- Il y a la possibilité d'une stigmatisation du mot « femme » par son sens second de « épouse » (radouxju), cela restreignant son emploi.
- Il y a en plus la possibilité d'utiliser le mot « mademoiselle » (Jean-Abdel), qui convient à tous les âges pourvu que l'on connaisse le statu marital ou qu'on puisse l'évaluer à partir de l'âge apparent.
- Il est vrai que si  «jeune femme » dans le même contexte d'utilisation que « jeune homme » n'est pas utilisé, « Mademoiselle » l'est.

On pourrait donc conclure que la raison superficielle est que l'équivalent de « jeune homme » est « mademoiselle » cela pouvant être dû au problème des deux sens du mot femme.
Cependant, la supposition première que le terme "marqué" est « jeune homme » n'est pas nécessairement la bonne; les termes consacrés quand on en vient à interpeller quelqu'un  sont « madame », « mademoiselle », « monsieur », et peut-être (moins systèmatique) « garçon » pour les jeunes garçons, d'ailleurs utilisé ainsi pour interpeller n'importe quel homme dont le travail est de servir aux tables des établissements qui fournissent nourriture et boissons. Selon ce point de vue la raison première peut ne plus se concevoir comme étant une stigmatisation du mot « femme » en cela que l'anomalie apparente de la non utilisation de « jeune femme » n'est pas une réalité et que le véritable problème serait plutôt le manque d'un équivalent systématique pour « mademoiselle » en ce qui concerne le genre masculin; on peut donc spéculer sur une raison plus profonde en rapport avec le terme « monsieur » , qui bien qu'appliqué à des êtres masculins de tous les âges, l'est de façon très irrégulière selon le milieux que l'on considère; il faut dire que la pratique vieille déjà d'une cinquantaine d'années et peut-être abandonnée qui a été celle de certains professeurs de collège d'appeler des élèves de 12 ans « Monsieur untel » et « Mademoiselle untel » est très très loin d'être un standard et que la voie du progrès dans le domaine de la politesse ne passe pas nécessairement par la généralisation de telles pratiques à toute la société. Si on ne peut pas parler d'une stigmatisation du mot « monsieur » on doit référer à une contrainte dans son utilisation, une contrainte assez subjective, laquelle rendrait l'utilisation du terme « jeune homme » pratique. Ce pourrait être le point de vue sûr lequel se baser dans une recherche de la vérité.

Comment: J'ai eu beau lire plusieurs fois votre réponse à votre propre question (!), on n'y comprend pas grand chose. Il faut faire un effort de synthèse.  De plus, plus personne ne s'adresse à un garçon de café en l'appelant "garçon", qui sent un peu la naphtaline dans cette acception.

Comment: @petitrien Évitez de lire mes réponses et ne perdez pas de temps avec ce qui ne vous apporte rien. De plus vous me  semblez être loin de tout connaitre de ce pays que vous habitez : mon père à utilisé cette formule pour s'adresser au garçons de café sa vie durant et il ne l'a certainement pas inventée ; de surcroit voici l'ngram de cet usage, avec un point d'exclamation : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gar%C3%A7on+%21&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGar%C3%A7on%20%21%3B%2Cc0 En hausse ces dernières années !

Comment: Vous confirmez ce que je dis, savoir que cette expression a été utilisée mais ne l'est plus.  Je continuerai à lire vos réponses, elles sont parfois tellement tartes (TLFi : Pop., fam. Sot, ridicule; laid., je vous donne la définition, ça vous évitera d'aller la chercher) qu'elles en deviennent drôles.

Comment: @petitrien Il n'y a pas besoin de vous lire longtemps pour savoir où se trouve le populaire, le vulgaire, le philistin … les paroles en l'air, le manque total de consistance dans les idées (sauf lorsqu'il s'agit de me harceler et de propager des commérages).

Comment: Je ne harcèle pas, je dégonfle les baudruches.

Comment: @petitrien Ça va, tant que vous vous amusez bien !