# L'enterrement de vie de (jeune) fille/garçon

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

En espérant que vous me pardonnerez pour ma question peu profonde, mais tout de même la petite différence entre

> L'enterrement de vie de jeune fille

et

> L'enterrement de vie de garçon

m'a interpellé. Je voulais donc savoir s'il y avait une raison pour laquelle le « jeune » a été laissé tomber.

Comment: Ces expressions n'étaient pas correctes telles qu'elles étaient écrites ; il faut toujours un déterminatif pour le mot « vie ».

Comment: @LPH Ces expressions sont parfaitement correctes.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah oui, depuis 2000. // La syntaxe de la phrase « En espérant que vous me pardonnerez pour ma question peu profonde, mais tout de même la petite différence entre « L'enterrement de vie de jeune fille  » et « L'enterrement de vie de garçon » 
m'a interpellé. » est complètement fausse.

Comment: @LPH Nous sommes au XXIe siècle depuis bientôt une génération. Il faut vivre avec son temps.

Comment: Autrement dit, la jeunesse, *terminée*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un jeune garçon est plus jeune qu'une jeune fille, et en tout cas pas en âge de se marier.

Si on souhaite utiliser *jeune* pour le masculin, on peut dire *enterrement de vie de jeune homme*, mais *de vie de garçon* est beaucoup plus courant.

J'ai déjà évoqué cette différence ici :
  [Cas particulier de position de l'adjectif : « jeune x » vs « x jeune »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31484/cas-particulier-de-position-de-ladjectif-jeune-x-vs-x-jeune/31534#31534)

Comment: Ah ok cool, en effet, quelque chose de similair se manifest en anglais aussi: young boy != young man mais yound girl ~= young lady (pas vraiment, mais certainement plus que young boy et young man). En tous cas merci, c'est moins idomatique que je pensais.